# FireDAC SQLITE with LEFT JOIN reassign NULL entries to an empty string results with Type Mismatch?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firedac

I'm trying to fix the sort order in a `TDBGrid` by changing NULL entries (for a `VARCHAR(255)`) to an empty string but I get:

> EDatabaseError with message 'Table1: Type mismatch for field 'MyName',
> expecting: String actual: WideString'.

The query in a `TFDQuery` looks like:

```
Select Table1.*, IFNULL(Table2.Name,'') AS MyName
From Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON (Table1.LinkField=Table2.UniqueId)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**More Info:**

If I set the `Params["StringFormat"]="ANSI"` that message goes away but then my existing text in a `TEXT` field turns to Chinese.

I now understand what the [FireDAC SQLite Mapping](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC) means.  In this case:

```
VARCHAR -> dtAnsiString, Len = L
TEXT -> dtWideMemo
```

How do I tell `IFNULL` to use a character string instead of a wide string?  `Table2.Name` is a `VARCHAR`.

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLLite supports the `CAST`  operator, which is what the standard SQL uses to declare the exact type that you need for an expression.

So in this case your query would be:

```
SELECT Table1.*, 
       IFNULL(Table2.Name, CAST('' as varchar(20))) AS MyName
FROM Table1
     LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.LinkField = Table2.UniqueId
```

PS: you won't need to change the query if you just drop the persistent field for the MyName field, and re-create it (right-click over the TFDQuery component, and chose the Field Editor option), so now it would create it as a TWideStringField, matching the new result for that query.

This is where you can check the class type of a component (the persistent field) through the Object Inspector:

[image]

Comment: I was looking at the persistent fields and didn't see any "type", it just had a generic data type.  but I did try the CAST and it didn't work, there were a bunch of details on another answer but it and they seemed to have been removed.  There is another one with more generic details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76215057/attempt-to-open-tfdquery-from-sqlite-db-created-with-unicode-createutf16-fails-w where if I use NVARCHAR or Unicode String format it fails (but maybe it's the persistent field and some hidden "type" no in the object inspector?)

Comment: @user3161924 I'm sorry about the problem with CAST, I have no experience with SQLLite to know what went wrong. But if you can't solve it then redeclaring the persistent field seems your only choice left.

Comment: @user3161924 On the persistent field, look at its Class type (besides the name on the very top of the Object Inspector), it should be TStringField, but if you re-create it, it will change to TWideStringField. If you don't want to drop and re-create the field, you can always change its class editing directly the DFM file and the declaration part of your form. Search for `object QMyQueryMyField: TStringField` and change it to TWideStringField. Same on the declaration part of your form.

Comment: The Object Inspector doesn't have a class.  But when I went directly to the .dfm file I see the `TStringField`.  All that wasted time because it's not in the Object Inspector.  Is there a way to make it show up or is it buried somewhere in there?

Comment: @user3161924 I have added a picture to the answer, so you can see where to check the class type on the Object Inspector. It's not within its properties but just above them.

Comment: AH I see it now - is there anyway to change it up there or you have to manually edit the .dfm or delete and recreate?

Comment: The answer is actually that the persistent fields needed the class type changed, then everything works as expected.

Comment: @user3161924 No, the only other way that I know, besides editing manually .dfm files, is to use some IDE plug-ins, like GExperts. But its quite finicky, so I just change it manually.