# Attempt to open TFDQuery from SQLITE DB created with Unicode/CreateUTF16 fails with error 'expecting: String actual: WideString', why?

Tags: sqlite, c++builder, firedac

I decided to move my C++Builder project from the SQLITE default of `StringFormat=Choose` and `OpenMode=CreateUTF8` to Unicode versions:

```cpp
SQLiteFDConnection->Params->Values["StringFormat"]=_T("Unicode");
SQLiteFDConnection->Params->Values["OpenMode"]=_T("CreateUTF16");
// NOTE: The same thing happens if I create it with:
//SQLiteFDConnection->Params->Values["OpenMode"]=_T("CreateUTF8");
```

I do this because the `VARCHAR` fields wouldn't take the Japanese characters (resulted with `??`).

However, I can't even open the new database with those two settings without getting this error:

> Project raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Table1: Type mismatch for field 'Name', expecting: String actual: WideString'.

`Name` is one of the `VARCHAR` items (first one).

In another post, it was mentioned to set the `TFDQuery`'s `Charset`, however in C++Builder it seems that there is no `FDQuery1.Params.Strings['Charset'] := UTF8Charset` option available.

The manual says for SQLITE when using `Unicode` string format that `VARCHAR` will be `UnicodeString`.

I must clearly be missing something, what is it?

**Additional:**

I reverted back to the defaults of `StringFormat=Choose` and `OpenMode=CreateUTF8`, but changed the `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` and that ends up with the exact same exception for any field that would use `NVARCHAR`.

It doesn't appear that it's properly doing the conversion as the [Using SQLite with FireDAC](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC) says it would.

To be clear, it's the `FDQuery->Open()` in the `AfterConnect` event that generates the exception.

Comment: Try setting `FDQuery1->Params->Values["Charset"] = "UTF8";`

Comment: `Values` doesn't exist.  Trying `FDQuery1->Params->ParamValues["Charset"] = "UTF8";` gives a run time error that parameter `Charset` not found.

Comment: added additional info to question.

Comment: Did you try setting the `Charset` param on the `TSQLiteFDConnection` instead of on the `TFDQuery`? On a side note, use `_D()` instead of `_T()` when assigning string literals to `System::(Unicode)String` objects. `_D()` will ensure the literal uses the `System::Char` data type (`wchar_t` on Windows, `char16_t` on other platforms), whereas `_T()` is from the C runtime and will make the literal use `char` or `wchar_t` based on the project's `TCHAR maps to` setting, which you don't want in this case.

Comment: I didn't see anything on Charset for the connection (other than the PRAGMA https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding).  But it looks like the main problem was persistent fields class type I didn't notice - I was looking down in the properties.   Thanks for the _D(), I wondered about all the obj to normal string conversion stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the **persistent fields** needed the class type changed from `TStringField` to `TWideStringField`, then everything works as expected. To change them I edited the `.dfm` file and also updated the .h file.